# Trim Funtion in Dataset Stored Procedure Causes SSRS report Fail

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an `SSRS` report. It have `multi valued parameters` & a `sub report`. It runs fine until I changed the `dataset` for a `parameter` ( In both `report`).  When I previewed the report it shows below error.

> "one or more parameters were not specified for the subreport located
>   at /report".

I tried below steps to resolve the issue

```
1. Ensured parameter names are correct.
2. removed rdl.data file
3. Deleted the dataset and recreated it.
```

I tried to revoke the changes made in `dataset` & the report runs `perfectly`. The only change I have made in the `dataset` was the addtion of  `LTRIM(RTRIM))` `Function` in `dataset query` to remove the spaces between `multi-value parameter.`

The dataset query was like below

```
select Loan_no 
From loan_header
where rowatatus = 'A'
```

I have changed it into

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Loan_no)) As Loan_no
From loan_header
where rowatatus = 'A'
```

When I removed `LTRIM(RTRIM)` `Function` from the `Dataset` query, the report works fine. So, use of `LTRIM(RTRIM) Function` causes the `Report` failure.
What will be reason behind this? Anyone facing similar issue before?. Please help.

Comment: can u show data set query?

Comment: edited the question please check

Comment: then i hope ltrim(rtim()) return a null value(empty string) ..Allow null for the parameter may resolve the issue

Comment: yeah . But since the parameter is multivalued it wont allow nulls!